# Juniper SRX 220

Tags: juniper-network-connect

I'm a newbie to Juniper and SRX. We have just setup a cluster with 2 Juniper SRX 220 devices and I’m just struggling to setup reth interfaces. The Juniper's have to 2 uplinks to a Cicso ASA. At the moment interface ge-0/0/0, ge-3/0/0 and ge-0/0/1, ge-/0/01 are connected to the ASA. I have setup a VLAN 's 192 and added the reth1 interface to this VLAN. I can ping the reth1 interface but cannot ping   interface  on the ASA interface at the other end. Please can someone advise what i have done wrong. Config below.

```
chassis {

cluster {

reth-count 2;

redundancy-group 0 {

node 0 priority 100;

node 1 priority 1;

}

redundancy-group 1 {

node 0 priority 100;

node 1 priority 1;

preempt;

interface-monitor {

ge-3/0/1 weight 255;

ge-0/0/1 weight 255;


}

}

}

}

interfaces {

interface-range interfaces-fwtransit {

member ge-0/0/0;

member ge-3/0/0;

unit 0 {

family ethernet-switching {

vlan {

members fwtransit;

}

}

}

}

ge-0/0/1 {

gigether-options {

redundant-parent reth1;

}

}

ge-0/0/3 {

unit 0 {

family inet {

address 10.100.0.252/24;

}

}

}

ge-3/0/1 {

gigether-options {

redundant-parent reth1;

}

}

fab0 {


fabric-options {

member-interfaces {

ge-0/0/5;

}

}

}

fab1 {

fabric-options {

member-interfaces {

ge-3/0/5;

}

}

}

reth0 {

vlan-tagging;

redundant-ether-options {

redundancy-group 1;

}

}

reth1 {

vlan-tagging;

redundant-ether-options {

redundancy-group 1;

}

unit 192 {

description untrust;

vlan-id 192;
family inet {

address 192.168.2.252/24;

}

}

}

vlan {

unit 0 {


family inet {

address 192.168.1.1/24;

}

}

unit 162 {

family inet {

address 172.31.254.3/24;

}

}

unit 192 {

family inet {

address 192.168.2.3/24;

}

}

}

}

routing-options {

static {

route 10.100.0.0/24 next-hop 10.100.0.1;

}

}

protocols {

stp;

}

security {

zones {

security-zone trust {

interfaces {

ge-0/0/3.0 {

host-inbound-traffic {

system-services {

ping;

https;

ssh;

}

}

}

}

}

security-zone untrust {

host-inbound-traffic {

system-services {

ping;

}

}

interfaces {

vlan.162;

vlan.192;

}

}

}

}

vlans {

fwtransit {

vlan-id 162;

l3-interface vlan.162;

}

web_dmz {
vlan-id 192;

l3-interface vlan.192;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you have something like this:
Topology:
[image]

As you already have the ICMP under the host-inbound-traffic you could check:

1. As an initial down/dirty test a security-policy permitting everything. A premise for this: "The Junos OS examines security policies if the traffic destination is any interface other than the incoming interface."

2.Monitor traffic on the interface, make sure that ICMP ECHOs are leaving the wire, if there is no reply, something on the ASA could be.

3. Have you checked interface statistics for drops or errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have configured the correct policies with:
- show configuration security policies

You can configure a policy with:

```
set security policy from-zone xxx to-zone xxx policy my-policy match source-address any destination-address any application any
set security policy from-zone xxx to-zone xxx policy my-policy then permit
```

and try to ping the ASA-Interface by specifying the source Interface:
- *ping x.x.x.xinterface ge-0/0/0*

maybe you also want to define a loopback Interface and add this Interface to your: "trust"-security-zone